nopCommerce/ASP.NET max file size upload limit reached
I am running nopCommerce (self hosted eCommerce store) on my linux debain server. nopCommerce uses ASP.NET I am trying to upload some files but they are too big.
Every forum I look at tells me to edit the "web.config" file but I can't find it anywere in the nopCommerce directery.
Can anyone help me.
I have looked at countles forums but come up empty handed.

it's a configuration file on the server. U don't see it in a "backoffice" or so. In general it is in the root of your web application.

Go to Admin --> Configuration --> Settings --> Media Settings
You can update Maximum image size as per your requirement
